# React - problems with copy-pasting navbars examples

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a question. Today I'm trying to react for the first time. I want to make fancy-looking navbar.

I opened that page:

[NavBar React example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/)

And copied some example. I pasted it to my `App.js` file. Now, its look like this:

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from "react-bootstrap";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        //here i posted my navbar
        <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="#brand">React-Bootstrap</a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
                Link
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
                Link
              </NavItem>
              <NavDropdown
                eventKey={3}
                title="Dropdown"
                id="basic-nav-dropdown"
              >
                <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem divider />
                <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
              </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
            <Nav pullRight>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
                Link Right
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
                Link Right
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
        ;
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And output looks like this:

[image]

Could you tell me, what I forget about? I'm new in a web application, so please be patient and forgiving. Of course, I will move navbar to separate component but for now, I want to look, how it works.

I get any errors in my Chrome console

Thanks for any pieces of advice!

Comment: did you install or add bootstrap ?

Comment: Yep, i installed it by  `npm install --save react-bootstrap`

Comment: @michasaucer but did you imported the css file?

Comment: yeah it was working for me thats why i asked you if you installed it so you missed this step and we answered at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `public` folder is `index.html` file. I just added this line:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

in `<head>` and works fine.

Comment: yeah i was surprised  beacause it was working for me so you missed this step

Answer (score 1):

Since the JSX tags from bootstrap are actually creating those respective html elements {unordered lists, list items, toggle buttons, etc}, we can assume bootstrap is at least loaded.

You should check the console to check if bootstrap styles are coming in for those elements. If not, be aware of the following found in the react-bootstrap doc's:

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components. How and which bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN.

check here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Also, There is a random semicolon at the end of the Navbar closing tag*

Hope this helps!

Comment: @michasaucer - Looks like this worked. Glad you're not having this issue anymore. Would you mind marking my answer as accepted? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

add this in you public index.html the stylesheet links from : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/